# Python, CSV, and Excel: Creating a text file with info side by side

Tags: excel, python-2.7, csv, xlrd, xlwt

I want to have this code make a text file with the info side by side as columns but right now it displays it as rows.

If you want the full code here is my pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/TeD78wQn

```
with open('file.txt','wb') as fou:
    writer = csv.writer(fou)
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
transposed = zip(*data)
with open('col_output.txt','wb') as fou:
    writer = csv.writer(fou)
    for row in transposed:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Edit: to remove spaces from your original data simply call `.strip()` when populating `data`:

```
data = []
data.append([sheet.cell_value(row, 0).strip() for row in range(sheet.nrows)])
data.append([sheet.cell_value(row, 1).strip() for row in range(sheet.nrows)])
```

Comment: On this original excel sheet there are spaces in between the text. Is there any way I can delete the space in the output.

Comment: I tried the edit and I didn't work. In the excel spreadsheet there is text in a few of the cells and then it skips line and then there are more cells with text. When I create both the excel file and text file it has those spaces in it. The excel file just has blank cells and the text file has commas for the lines.

Comment: Oh, can you somehow remove those skipped lines beforehand? Otherwise you could skip them in the Python code.

Comment: I can't remove those lines from the excel spreadsheet because there is useful information on the other columns for those rows and I tried adding the .strip() like shown in the code but it didn't change